# Why $\mathbb E[\mathbb 1_A X]=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb E[X]$?

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space, $X$ a random variable and $A\in \mathcal F$. Why $$\mathbb E[X\mathbb 1_A]=\mathbb P(A)\mathbb E[X]\ \ ?\tag{F}$$

**Attempts**

Set $Y=\mathbb 1_A$. Then, $$\mathbb E[X\mathbb 1_A]=\sum_{y\in \{0,1\}}\int_{\mathbb R}xy\mathbb P(X\in dx, Y\in dy)=\int_{\mathbb R}x\mathbb P(X\in dx, Y=1).$$

For the formula $(F)$ to be true we should have $$\mathbb P(X\in E, Y=1)=\mathbb P(X\in E)\mathbb P(Y=1),$$
for all $E\in \mathcal F$, but this would prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. And I don't know why it should be the case.

Comment: this wouldn't prove $X$ and $Y$ independent, because $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$ does not prove independence.



You could prove your statement via the tower property of expectation for $\mathbb{E}[X]\neq 0$, $\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{1}_A]\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly false. For example if $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $A=(X>0)$ then RHS is $0$ and LHS $>0$.